# TensorFlow tf.nn.rnn function ... how to use the results of your training to do a single forward-pass through the RNN

Tags: tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network, lstm

I'm having a tough time using the 'initial state' argument in the tf.nn.rnn function.

```
val, _ = tf.nn.rnn(cell1, newBatch, initial_state=stateP, dtype=tf.float32)
```

newBatch.shape => (1, 1, 11)
stateP.shape => (2, 2, 1, 11)

In general, I've gone through the training for my LSTM neural net and now I want to use the values of it.  How do I do this?  I know that the tf.nn.rnn() function will return state... but I don't know how to plug it in.

fyi stateP.shape => (2, 2, 1, 11) ..... maybe because I used stacked LSTM cells?

I've also tried:

```
val, _ = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(stacked_lstm, newBatch, initial_state=stateP, dtype=tf.float32)
```

but I get the error "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'op'".
I'm pretty sure that the 'NoneType' object being talked about is the stateP tuple I gave, but I'm not sure what to do here.

**EDIT:  I finally got this running by using:**

```
init_state = cell.zero_state(batch_size, tf.float32)
```

To determine the exact shape I need to pass into the 'initial_state' argument.  In my case, it was a TUPLE of 4 tensors, each with the shape of (1, 11).  I made it like this:

```
    stateP0 = tf.convert_to_tensor(stateP[0][0])
    stateP1 = tf.convert_to_tensor(stateP[0][1])
    stateP2 = tf.convert_to_tensor(stateP[1][0])
    stateP3 = tf.convert_to_tensor(stateP[1][1])
    newStateP = stateP0, stateP1, stateP2, stateP3
```

Alright!  Now the tf.dynamic_rnn()  function is working, but it's giving me different results every time I run it.... so what's the point of passing in the initial state?  I want to use the state I trained to find... and I don't want it to change.  I want to actually use the results of my training!

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using the deprecated (or soon to be) behavior. `stateP` in your case represents the concatenation of `c` (cell state) and `h` (output of lstm from the final step of unrolling). So you need to slice the state along dimension 1 to get the actual state.

Or, you can initialize your LSTM cell with `state_is_tuple=True`, which I would recommend, so that you could easily get the final state (if you want to tinker with it) by indexing the state `stateP[0]`. Or you could just pass the state tuple directly to rnn (or dynamic_rnn).

I cant say anything beyond that because you have not provided your initialization code. So I would be guessing.

You can edit your question to provide more details if you still face problems and I would edit the answer.

Comment: thanks, it turned out to be a shape issue.  I was always using state_is_tuple=True, but just had trouble reformatting the shape needed by the initial_state argument.  But now, the more fundamental question is:  How do I use this 'machine-learned-magic' state, consistently?  I just want to run data through a LSTM NN architecture, and the result of that should be the same every time if the data is the same... but that's not what I'm seeing with the tf.nn.rnn() function.  I'm getting different results!